# Isolate database performance on an instance

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition installed on a machine with two different users and two catalogs, each of them accessed by a different user (each user is strictly tied to his catalog).

Is it possible that a time consuming operation on a catalog slows down operations on the other? How can I avoid that?

The physical server machine has four cores assigned, so I assume SQL Server can use more than one of them, but I have not configured anything explicitly.

Comment: Did you install two instances of SQL Server or did you create two different databases on the same SQL Server instance ? The machine you installed the database service on are the user logged onto the machine or is it a network server ?

Comment: I have only one SQL Server engine (only one instance) with two different catalog.
The machine is a server (virtual ones) on the network, now it has 4 core dedicated to SQL Server istance.
I have one user to log in (using remote desktop) and made some mantainance operation but other users log using SSMS directly on SQL Server engine (there are onyl three users, the first for the catalog one , the second for the second catalog and the third is mine for administrative pourpose)

Answer (score 1):

You're question is very broad.  But in general the answer is yes.  A single instance has to share resources across all databases unless configured specifically not to.
By default, SQL uses all available CPU's for all operations.  You can configure MAXDOP (max degree of parallelism) on the database so a single query will only have access to that many CPU's.
IO is another tricky issue.  Generally it's best to seperate your workloads on physical hardware whenever possible.  Logs, data and tempdb all on seperate physical storage.  In addition, if you are trying to create a seperation of resources for the databases, you can use filegroups to assign the objects or the entire database to a separate storage device.
There are many, many other answers but again.  The question of 'how can I avoid that?'(in terms of cross database resource allocation) is way too broad for a specific answer.  If you are looking at one aspect, say IO, or CPU usage, it's an easier, more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at the time i had write the question, what i'm looking for was a way to assign a limited amount of resource per catalog.
Nowdays i ended up with accept the fact that is not possible to do what i would.
As far as i know now it's possible achieve a somewhat separation using CPU affinity and other tricks, but there is not a way to strictly enforce which resource (or amounth of them) are used by which catalog.

Comment: I think as I said before, your question is a bit too broad.  If you have an actual performance problem you wish to address, that might make for more specific answers.  As far as separation of resources by Catalog, SQL has a ton of options to do just that.  I wouldn't recommend blindly implementing any of those options without a definitive reason.  Doing it for the sake of doing it is just a bad idea.  Generally, SQL is very good at balancing resources on it's own.

Comment: No i had a system where sometimes testing on test catalog cause an hang in the production catalog. But that happened 3 yars ago.
Today the environments are splitted on two different VM with two separate SQL Engine and we have solved the problem in that way.